# iOS 9 Swift UIView has no member

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7

I used swift auto layout.

This is the code

```
overlayView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

This was worked perfectly in iOS 8. But in xcode 7 it is not working. It is giving the error

```
Value of type 'UIView' has no member setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It now seems to be:

`view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

I think they changed it to be more consistent with the general pattern for properties in Swift in Swift 2